# Append a column to dataframe using withColumn and callUDF

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I am trying to add a new column to a given dataframe based on the other columns of same dataframe.

map is a String-Boolean map

Below is my code.

```
    hiveContext.udf().register("udfname", new UDF2<String, String, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(String col1, String col2) throws Exception {
            return map.get(col1+col2);
        }
    }, DataTypes.BooleanType);

    DataFrame newDF = df.withColumn("newcol", calUDF("udfname" ,df.col("col1"),df.col("col2")));
```

I am getting compilation error.

```
 The method calUDF(String, Column, Column) is undefined for the type myclass
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use callUDF, but I solved it by making a query having the udf.

Select col1,col2, udfname(col1,col2) as newCol3 from table.
Above will give me new dataframe with new column with its value populated based on other columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is really late, but the problem was most likely due to a typo as you were missing the second l in call. You would also need to make sure you had callUDF imported, but if udf worked then you probably did.